# How to change the color of the view behind a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like to change the color of the "view" behind my table view (the view controller is a UITableViewController). Currently, the view is black so when my table view slides in, via push, I see it through the transparent navigation bar during the transition. Is there a way to change its color? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently needed to do this in my app as well and found that: `self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];` does the trick

Answer (score 1):

Can you just set the background color of the tableViewController?

```
yourTableViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Try, in your applicationDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean self.view.backgroundColor? That will just change the color of the table view not the view behind it.

Comment: I think you might be referring to the window, try this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `backgroundColor` on the `backgroundView` property of the `tableView`

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
self.tableView.backgroundView  = backgroundView;
```